# How do I work with Word Documents without using COM Automation?

Tags: delphi, automation, ms-word

I have read multiple posts on the issue, and none seem to come to a decent conclusion to my question. (Perhaps I'm trying to see if anything has popped up lately.)

I have a small charity app that handles pledges. In doing so, it needs to work with and print  documents.

Thing is, if Word is open in the background, the app thread will hang and won't respond to the closure of Word, and I have to roll back manually and close word. Sure, that all works fine, but I simply cannot guarantee that the end user will close Word, even if I put the instruction in a user manual.

I'm not too fussed about speed, but I guess that if it can be enhanced, it would be a nice little bonus.

Have any libraries been released for Delphi that will allow me to open, edit, print, and save documents? If not, is there a way to use Word Automation in such a way that it will not conflict with another open handle of Word when opened?

Comment: You can try Aspose on .net. Nothing as comprehensive for Delphi. Perhaps the best option is to use something other than a Word document. Something text file based.

Comment: I'm not terribly keen on writing wrappers and things, if that is even possible with Aspose. I haven't really looked at it anyway, simply because it is .Net. To be honest, Word gives me the best flexibility with documents, especially for an end user. So not using Word is not really an option. Thanks though. :)

Comment: *The app thread will hang*, on which call exactly?

Comment: Upon opening an instance of Word itself. Before I've even started.

Comment: If all you need to do is print stuff, then have you considered just calling `ShellExecute(0, 'print', 'foo.doc', ...)`?

Comment: Also need to edit, sorry - not being very explanatory here.

Comment: you may try implementing Netscape Plugin APi host: last MS Office version come with NPAPI plugin for browsers. But since NP API is public - you can pretend being browser and try to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `GetActiveOleObject`, you will get the running instance of Word. 
By using `CreateOleObject`, you will get a new instance and shouldn't be troubled by other running instances.

In case you use the `TWordApplication`, wrapper you can set `ConnectKind` to `ckNewInstance` to accomplish this. By default, TWordApplication will try to connect with a running instance.

Comment: Is there a way to set ConnectKind (or something similar) without using TWordApplication? I tend to prefer using raw Ole functions, if you know what I mean. I do use CreateOleObject.

Comment: Why do you prefer later bound COM? Surely early bound is better.

Comment: I could do, and it isn't a terrible idea, but is it the only way I can change ConnectKind? I'm sure there are a few other benefits of early-binding, but I'm not sure if I need them.

Comment: No, I think ConnectKind only toggles between trying to GetActiveOleObject, or always CreateOleObject, if you already use CreateOleObject that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The difference between early and late binding, is between using interfaces or variants, right? You can still use the interfaces if you use CreateOleObject. TWordApplication is only a Delphi component wrapper.

Comment: @David, that's what I assumed. Now, perhaps we need to find out why the app hangs if word is open... Even when no dialog box is open, which I find quite weird. I'll update my question with the code that I'm currently using once I get home this evening.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open edit and print Word documents and you don't mind using RTF format for what you're doing, investigate [TRichView](http://www.trichview.com/).

It will generate rich documents that are in RTF format, which is one of the formats MS word supports. I don't think it directly reads .DOC files but you can convert .DOC and .DOCX into RTF, for most simple files, but certain advanced formatting features would be lost in the conversion.

It has the advantage of working without any need for even any copy of MS Word to be installed on the machine that is going to do the document processing.  For production of receipts and other simple documents, this would be the most reliable technique; Don't use Word  directly, at all.

Comment: The problem with the RTF file format is that headers and footers are not supported, so far as I know. It would be unwise to limit a customer's capabilities. Its the same reason that I won't fully migrate to OpenOffice for this purpose (while it is supported).

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure PrintViaWord (const filename: string);
const
 wdUserTemplatesPath = 2;

var
  wrdApp, wrdDoc, wrdSel: variant;

begin
 wrdApp:= CreateOleObject ('Word.Application');   // create new instance
 sleep (5000);    // this fixes a bug in Word 2010 to do with opening templates
 wrdDoc:= wrdApp.documents.add (
          wrdApp.Options.DefaultFilePath[wdUserTemplatesPath] + '\mytemplate.dot');

 wrdDoc.Select;
 wrdSel:= wrdApp.selection;
 wrdApp.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType:= 0;
 wrdSel.paragraphformat.alignment:= 1;
 wrdSel.typetext ('This is a program demonstrating how to open Word in the background'
                  + ' and add some text, print it, save it and exit Word');
 wrdDoc.SaveAs (filename + '.doc');
 wrdApp.ActivePrinter:= 'Konica Minolta 211';
 wrdApp.PrintOut;
 WrdDoc.SaveAs (filename + '.doc');
 wrdApp.quit;

 wrdSel:= unassigned;
 wrdDoc:= unassigned;
 wrdApp:= unassigned
end;
```